# Button from master page not accessible where the button in overlapped by a div tag in Home page. Asp.net website

Tags: asp.net, html, css

I have a div tag in my home page for login form, and in my master page I have the signout button, When the user log in I hide the text box and lable used in the login form and the signout button is made visible after the user login. My problem is the signout button cant be clicked in the home page, where as in other pages I am able to click the sign out button, I think in home page the signout is exactly behind the div tag,

Home Page

```
<div id="loginBox"> 
     ....
     login form
      text box 
      label

</div>
```

Master Page

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="btn_signout" CssClass="link" Height="22px" 
  Width="72px" runat="server" OnClick="Btn_singout_Click"
  >Sign Out</asp:LinkButton>    

#loginBox
{
    top: -140px;
    left: 472px;
    position: relative;
    width: 400px;
    height: 92px;

}
```

Is this problem because of the div tag that is placed exactly where the div tag is placed? I tried to move the signout in other area of header where the div tag doesnt overlap the signout button, and I was able to click the signout button then, If the div tag overlaps the sigout button I am not able to click the signout in home page. Any idea about where I am wrong? thanks

Comment: It would be more helpful, if you paste the exact html of your master and home page.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try setting the z-index for loginBox?